# I can no longer copy & paste from clipboard into SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, copy-and-paste

A few weeks ago, I was able to copy/paste an image from the clipboard into a rich textbox in SharePoint Online. I just realised that this feature is no longer available.I have tried with Chrome, Firefox and IE (all latest version) but nothing seems to work. When I paste the image in - it just shows the clip icon:

[image]

Is there a way to get this back?